# Usb devices stop working as soon as applications access powered usb webcam

Tags: usb, power-management, webcam

My mouse and keyboard stop working when i plug in my webcam.

I use a docking station. Now as soon as I plug in the camera to the docking station and start an app that streams the webcam image, the other devices stop working (mouse and camera). If I plug either of them directly into my laptop they work again.

I initially thought this was a power issue. So I attached a powered USB hub to my docking station and put the camera into this USB hub.
It did not work so I assume it is not a power issue. Any thoughts on what the issue could be?
This is the usb-devices output for camera and mouse

The devices work when simultaneously plugged into the laptop directly.
I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=03 Prnt=09 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 14 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=32 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=03f0 ProdID=a407 Rev=03.21
S:  Manufacturer=HP
S:  Product=HP Link-5 micro dongle
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=03 Lev=03 Prnt=09 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#= 12 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=145f ProdID=0203 Rev=00.05
S:  Manufacturer=Sunplus IT Co 
S:  Product=Trust USB Camera
S:  SerialNumber=20200707002
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
```

Again, the devices connected to the dock (via a powered USB hub) stop working as soon as an application actually uses the webcam and not before. Any tips how I could go further with debugging or solving the problem?

Comment: Look for firmware updates for the dock.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't resolved the problem. I have two 1920*1200 displays on there, as well as a mouse, keyboard, and USB Headset. Could this be a bandwidth issue

Comment: If you plug the mouse, keyboard, and webcam directly into the computer, without the dock connected, do they all work?

Comment: What brand/model dock? How did you update the firmware?

Comment: Its a HP Elite Thunderbolt-3-Dock. I have dualboot. I updated it on Windows to the latest version available of the official HP driver download page. The notebook is a HP Z-Book 15 G3.

Regarding your first question, yes they do!

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: That is: N81 Ver. 01.16

Comment: Did you try the current kernel version? When you managed to update your firmware and bios without destroying anything, you might also be able to compile and install the current version of linux with the updated drivers.

Comment: I am on 4.15.0-123-generic. You mean update to the current mainline kernel? Ughhh I am afraid that'll cause many issues.

Comment: If you know what you are doing its fine.
You simply copy the current configuration of the kerne, set the newly introduced parametrs to their defaults and hope that you don't mess up proprietary drivers.

Comment: You could also try a more recent live-usb release prior to the update of the natively installed linux installation to the upstream kernel version.

Comment: I have tried it with the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version and I am still experiencing the same issue. Btw. The issue persists with different cameras from different manufacturers. I give up...

Answer (score 0):

**Dock**

HP Elite Thunderbolt 3 65W Dock

We updated the dock firmware using the updaters found [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elite-thunderbolt-3-65w-dock/9822172).

**BIOS**

HP Z-Book 15 G3

You have BIOS version "N81 Ver. 01.16", dated Jun 18, 2017... N81 is the family ROM code.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 01.52 Rev.A, dated Nov 1, 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-15-g3-mobile-workstation/8693763).

Note: Select Windows OS to see the BIOS update.

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: I have updated my BIOS version to Ver. 01.52. However, I am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @FloRyan Disconnect one/both video monitors from the dock and see what happens to the mouse/keyboard/webcam.

Comment: The problem persists even with one monitor only. The problem appears to be on the Linux side as the dock works as expected under Windows. My Usb Hub has a status LED for each port. This led is not consistently on when runnig on Linux.

Comment: @FloRyan I'm out of ideas then. Sorry.